# Firebase List Constantly Refreshing

Tags: list, firebase, swiftui

I am still trying to figure out swiftui. I am writing a program that utilizes a database for a grocery app. I decided to go with Google Firebase and so far so good. The issue I have though is I am trying to load a list of products and this list is constantly refreshing. When I scroll it refreshes and I am back at the top of the list. I was wondering if I could get some help as to what I am doing wrong here. I will include my code below and try to best explain. Thanks in advance!

```
struct ContentView: View {
      @State var selectedIndex = 0

      var body: some View {
           VStack {
                Button( action: {
                     selectedIndex = 5
                } label: {
                     Image(systemName: "magnyfyingglass")
                }
           }
           switch selectedIndex {
           case 0:
                // some code
           case 1:
                // some code
           case 2:
                // some code
           case 3:
                // some code
           case 4:
                // some code
           case 5:
                SearchView()
           default
                // some code
           }
     }
 }
```

SearchView looks like this:

```
struct SearchView: View {
      @State private var searchText = ""
      @ObservedObject var listModel = InvListView()

      var body: some View {
           NavigationView {
                List {
                     ForEach(self.listModel.invList.filter{(self.searchText.isEmpty ? true : $0.description.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(self.searchText))}, id: \.id) {products in

                     NavigationLink(destination: Detail(data: products)) {
                          Text(products.description)
                          }
                     }
                }
                .searchable(text: self.$searchText)
                {
                     ForEach(listModel.invList, id:\.id) {info in
                          HStack {
                               Text(info.description)
                                    .searchCompletion(info.description)
                          }
                     }
                }
           }
      }
 }

 struct Detail: View {
      var data: InventoryList

      var body: some View {
           VStack {
                Text(data.description)
                Text(data.category)
           }.padding()
      }
 }
```

InventoryList

```
 import Foundation
 import Firebase

 class InvListView: ObservableObject {


     @Published var invList = [InventoryList]()


     init() {
         // Access inventory in the database
         let database = Firestore.firestore()
    

         database.collection("inventory").getDocuments { snapshot, error in
        

             if error != nil {
                 // Errors will fix later
                 return
             }
        

             if let snapshot = snapshot {

                 DispatchQueue.main.async {

                     self.invList = snapshot.documents.map { d in

                         return InventoryList(id: d.documentID,
                                         upc: d["upc"] as? Int ?? 0,
                                         description: d["description"] as? String ?? "",
                                         category: d["category"] as? String ?? "",
                                         price: d["price"] as? Double ?? 0.0,
                                         url: d["imageUrl"] as? String ?? "")
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }

 struct InventoryList: Identifiable {
     var id: String
     var upc: Int
     var description: String
     var category: String
     var price: Double
     var url: String
 }
```

I hope this is enough to go on. I think it has something to do either with the switch or the init but not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out on my own. The `@ObservedObject` in `SearchView` was causing the view to refresh. I changed it to `@StateObject` and that seemed to fix the problem. There were some small bugs after, but once I removed them everything else worked.